# TWO SUM PROBLEM IN JAVA - I coded the below code but unable to find the problem in this

Tags: arrays, sum

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices    of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and    you may not use the same element twice.
You can return the answer in any order.
Example 1:
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9 Output: [0,1] Explanation:    Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].

Hi Team,

Above is my problem statement  and below is the code i coded.

```
   
                           Online Java Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug java program online. Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to execute it.
*******************************************************************************/
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums={2,7,8,0};
        int target=9;
    
        int s=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++) 
            {
                s=s+nums[i][j];
            }
            if(s==target)
            {
                System.out.print("["+i+","+j+"]");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I am unable to understand what's the problem with compilation ,could    anyone help!->Main.java:20: error: array required, but int found    s=s+nums[i][j];    it shows this error`enter code here`

Comment: I am not able to get what's the problem in this code.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `s=s+nums[i][j];` you are accessing `nums` as 2D array.

But you defined the variable `nums` as a 1D array.

Reply if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int nums[],int target) {
        int arr[]=new int[2];
       
        System.out.print("Array Elements : [");
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            System.out.print(nums[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
        System.out.println("Target : "+target);


        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++){
                if(nums[i]+nums[j] == target){
                    arr[0]=i;
                    arr[1]=j;
                    System.out.println("["+i+","+j+"]");      
             }else if(i==0 && j==0){
                    arr[0]=i;
                    arr[1]=j;
            }
            break;
        } 
    }
    return arr;
  }
```

}
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
  int[] indexes = new int[2];

    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++){
            if(target ==nums[i]+nums[j]){
                indexes[indexes.length-2] =i;
                indexes[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return indexes;  
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. It will be helpful for the author if you can elaborate the suggestions/changes you made in the code.